# Registry key error if the folder doesn't exist in VB

Tags: vb.net, registry

I am trying to add a registry key in to the file "MyApp" which doesn't yet exist in the registry key directory, when I try and write this key however I get an error from the debug console telling me the "NullReference was unhanded". If I go and manually make this folder it works brilliantly, so can anyone help me as I thought that this code would make the folder as well? If you could show me what code needs to also be there I would be very grateful!

The code I am using is:

```
    My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\MyApp", True).SetValue("AppName", "SerialKey")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\MyApp", True)` will open the key for write access only if it already exists. If the key doesn't exist, it will return null. Since you are blindly calling `SetValue` on a null reference, you will get the null reference exception.

The simplest solution to your requirement is to call `CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\MyApp")` instead. This does exactly what you want, i.e. creates a new subkey or opens the existing subkey for write access.

Answer (score 0):

adding and editing LocalMachine registry key needs administrator privilege in win 7, may be you are getting the error because of this